# Using dollar sign in shell scripting

Tags: shell

Im new with shell scripting , and i wonder when we use `$` sign with variables and when we don't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $ when you want the value of the variable. Omit it when you are initializing the variable

```
FOO='Bob'
echo "Hello $FOO"
```